# custom DevOps notification subscription via REST call

Tags: rest, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to create an Azure DevOps notification subscription via REST call. The recipient email address needs to be passed in and not default to my own email address. The ultimate goal is to programmatically create subscriptions so that certain non-ADO users can be automatically alerted about the resolution of work items that are relevant to them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> custom DevOps notification subscription via REST call

To create the notification subscription, you could use this REST API [Subscriptions - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
POST https://{service}.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/notification/subscriptions?api-version=6.0
```

Sample Request body:

```
{
  "description": "A new work item enters our area path",
  "filter": {
    "eventType": "ms.vss-work.workitem-changed-event",
    "criteria": {
      "clauses": [],
      "groups": [],
      "maxGroupLevel": 0
    },
    "type": "Expression"
  },
  "subscriber": {
    "id": "xxxxxxd71-c2fef2ad085f"
  },
  "channel": {
    "type": "EmailHtml",
    "address": "myteam@fabrikam.org",
    "useCustomAddress": true
  }
}
```

Just set the the recipient email address in the `"address": "xxxxx"`.

**Note:** You need provide the [eventType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/event%20types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and [subscriber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/subscriptions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and so on.

My test result:

[image]

[image]